# how to retrieve a stdClass Object Array thats located inside another array

Tags: php

I've got an array `Address` located inside an array $array1

```
[Address] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Address1] => xxxxxx
            [City] => xxxxx
            [State] => xxxxx
            [Zip] => xxxxxxx
        )
```

I attempted to call print_r($array1['Address']) but that doesnt work.  Does the stdClass Object require that I call it differently?

### This is my setup

I've got `$array1` being set up inside a function called `CALL_FUNCTION`.  Inside the function, I use `return $array1` to get access to the array outside the function.

Outside the function, I've got this...

```
$array1 = array();
$array1 = CALL_FUNCTION();
```

If I do `print_r($array1)` it returns the array with the above std object array inside of it.

Comment: yes you need the `->` arrow to access properties

Comment: If you got this via `json_decode()` and wanted an array instead of a stdObject add `true` as the 2nd argument. `json_decode($yourString,true);`

Comment: What doesn't work?  What's the error?  Are you sure $array1 is actually an array?

Comment: @Devon - yes I can print_r($array1) and it returns the entire array, including the std object array $Address.  Thats what I copied and pasted into my question.

Comment: @MrGlass - I've never dealt with json_decode before. How do I go about implementing that.  I've pasted updates to the question explaining how the code is set up.

Comment: @Ghost - I know I can use the `->` to access individual elements inside the std object array; however, I'm trying to actually return the array as an actual array.  Not individual objects.  If I can.

Comment: @KDJ, I assumed you were decoding json based on the array of stdObjects (it is a common issue when dealing with json). What code is in the `CALL_FUNCTION()` that is returning the array? That is where your stdObject comes from.

Comment: @MrGlass -  It is a SOAP call to a credit card processing company.  But it does not use json decode in it.  It uses `$client->SEND($Properties);` to set the array.

Comment: @KDJ Show the full dump of $array1 or show an error message.  ALWAYS make sure you have error reporting enabled during development.

Comment: is this some kind of third party library class? maybe there's a method that return an array, if not, you can probably cast it into array yourself

Comment: @Devon - ITs a standard error message regarding not being able to return a STD Object as an array... `Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: @KDJ  Exactly, and since you're not trying to access keys of Address, it means that $array1 is actually the object that it's reporting the error on.  Error messages are very useful, always make sure you include them in your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$array1 is not an array, it's also an object as indicated by the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Having `$array1 = array()` doesn't do anything since you aren't using `$array1` and are instantly reassigning it to the return value of `CALL_FUNCTION()`.

Access it as an object: `$array1->Address->Address1`.

However, you'll want to change the name of `$array1` to something like `$userObject` for the sake of future programmers who come across your code.

Comment: array1 was actually a dummy name....its not actually the name of the array in the code.  It made it easier to understand the question.  I will stick to using the standard `->` to access the object values.  Was trying something different...but it wasnt as easy as I was hoping it would be.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to an array

```
// get your array
$array1 = CALL_FUNCTION();

// cast the stdObject to an array
$array1['Address'] = (array) $array1['Address'] ;
```

Comment: That'd result in the same error...  You'd want the `(array)` type casting before CALL_FUNCTION().  But really, there's no indication the OP needs this unnecessary conversion

Comment: @Mr Glass - Thank you for the effort.  This unfortunately didnt work.  I will stick to using the standard method of `->` for accessing individual object variables.  It was worth a shot I guess.  Not as easy as it seemed it would be.

Comment: @KDJ, it didn't work? I tested it before I posted the code. Casting the stdObject using `(array)` give me an array.

Comment: @MrGlass because both $array1 and $array['Address'] are stdClass objects, not arrays.  You'd need to do multiple casts to get them both to an array.

Comment: @Devon, your sample data and code do not indicate that `array1` is a stdObject. You present it as an array, not a stdObject.